# Problem with pexpect and asyncio in python 3.8.5.It doesn't work

Tags: python, networking, python-asyncio, pexpect

```
import netdev
import asyncio
import yaml
import asyncio
from pprint import pprint
import re
import pexpect
import os



async def async_cisco(ip_device):
    login 
    password 
    t = pexpect.spawn('ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 {}@{}'.format(login, ip_device), timeout=10)
    i = await t.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF, 'User Name:', '\(yes\/no\)'])
    print(i)


async def send_command_to_devices(devices):
    coroutines = [async_cisco(device) for device in devices]
    result_all = await asyncio.gather(*coroutines, return_exceptions=True)
    for device, result in zip(devices, result_all):
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print(f"problen on {device}", result)
    return result_all

if __name__ == "__main__":
    devices = ['10.1.17.19','10.1.17.20']
    result = asyncio.run(send_command_to_devices(devices))
```

Can somebody help, I tried to connect to old cisco switches and got error

> [TypeError("object int can't be used in 'await' expression")]

I  want to set pexpect inside asyncio to connect lots of devices simultaneously
before that I used netdev(this vendor is not supported by netdev), and it was ok, but here I cant understand where is my problem, please help..

Comment: You can only `await` an awaitable object, typically a coroutine. You might be able to convert `t.expect()` into one by using `asyncio.to_thread()`.

Comment: thanks I hav e already found the problem